# Solutions of a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove $y_1(x) , y_2(x)$ are solutions of $W(y_1, y_2)(x)y'' -W(y_1 , y_2)'(x)y' + W(y_1' , y_2')(x)y=0$ if they are differentiable twice

I calculated the wronskians and noticed the ODE is Euler's equation but have no idea how to continue, it looks very complicated to solve with Euler's method

Comment: just put and take formal derivatives .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider why
$$
\det\pmatrix{y_1&y_2&y\\y_1'&y_2'&y'\\y_1''&y_2''&y''}=0
$$
for $y=y_{1,2}$ and expand the determinant for its last column.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\begin{align*}
W(y_1,y_2)&=y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2\\
W(y_1,y_2)'&=y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2\\
W(y_1',y_2')&=y_1'y_2''-y_1''y_2'
\end{align*}$$
Try substituting these expressions into the left-hand side of the equation and see what you get.